# Docker command issue

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I was trying to run the following command docker command:`docker run -d --name mongodbtest \ -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin \ -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \ -p 27017:27017 mongo` while following a tutorial (for using mongodb with spring boot) but this error showed up `"docker run" requires at least 1 argument.See 'docker run --help'`. I have tried changing it up in some ways but it did not work. After checking the available options from `docker run --help` I still couldn't find any issue as all of the options seemed correct.

Comment: Is the command exactly like you've shown it, with backslashes in the middle of the line?  Or is it on multiple lines?

Comment: @DavidMaze it is on multimple lines